# django orm AND condition for same key with multiple options

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

ihave a model **WebDocuments** with multiple objects of different document type and i want to apply and condition

```
    document_type= ['PAN', 'DL']
    doc_obj = WebDocuments.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    q_objects = Q()
    if document_type:
        q_objects &= [Q(type=doc) for doc in document_type]
    check_obj = doc_obj.filter(q_objects)
    if check_obj:
        return True
    return False
```

i want to return True or False wheather both document type exist of not.
i have both document type in my db still it returning empty because it filtering both type on save object .
is there is any way to do it with and operator or i have to loop queryset with all doc types

here is my model

```
class WebDocuments(TimeStampedModel):
   uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, null=True, blank=True)
   lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, related_name='web_lead_document')
   type = models.CharField(choices=DocumentTypeChoices.choices, max_length=100)
```

Comment: A `type` has only one value, it can not be `PAN` and `DL` at the same time.

Comment: so how can i check for both type

Comment: Do you mean an `or` condition ? So your result set contains instances of `type=PAN` AND `type=DL` ? Then it would be `q_objects |= [Q(type=doc) for doc in document_type]`

Comment: @steveharvey: the "and" condition makes no sense. You can retrieve `Webdocument` that have as type `PAL` or `DL`, but not both at the same time.

Comment: i want if any of document does not exist it return None

Answer (score 0):

Refer these -
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplechoicefield-django-forms/
https://www.teckiy.com/support/questions/how-to-setup-multi-choice-field-in-django-along-with-django-filter-3033665043/

or create new model naming Type and add it to WebDocuments model with type of many to many field and then query it.